# How to disable Custom Events

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, twig

I am trying to debug my problem. I have imported a library that will extract YouTube URLs from a playlist. Once this library is finished the extraction process, it will fire an event with `$(document).trigger('playlistDone');`. I then listen for the event via:

```
$(document).on('playlistDone', function() {
   alert( 'done' );
});
```

I never receive the alert though. My website is currently massive, so it is difficult to debug. I have verified that the library is indeed working by creating a blank page, and the library does indeed fire off the trigger. This leads me to believe something on my site is causing the problem.

I have also done:

```
$(document).on('click', function() {
   alert( 'done' );
});
```

to verify that default events are not disabled. My next step is to determine if somehow custom events are disabled.

To note, my website is using Bootstrap and Twig. I pray that they are not responsible for my issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hard to tell without seeing more source code, but one way to find out if the event has been registered is to check the events data object.

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/AerUL/4/)

**JS**

```
$(document).on('playlistDone', function(){
    alert('hello world'); 
}); 

//jQuery 1.8+
alert($._data(document, 'events').playlistDone); 
alert($._data(document, 'events').playlistDone.length); 

//Execute the first event
$._data(document, 'events').playlistDone[0].handler();

// < jQuery 1.8
//alert($.data(document, 'events').myCustomevent); ​
```

Comment: An alert is popping up with an object. Does this mean that my event has been registered and therefore not disabled? If so, how come my `on()` function is not acknowledging my event?

Comment: It means that the event exists. The second alert indicates how many event handlers are listening. If you get "Null" or "Undefined" then it means that the event does not exist.

Comment: Hmm... so my event does exist, but `on()` is not acknowledging it. Its progress at least :)

Comment: You can also try executing the attached function(s), see my updated example.

Comment: I am using jQuery 1.7.2 if that makes a difference.

Comment: Strange, it's probably an issue with the order of events, you'll need to make sure that your event is registered before your library begins loading URLs. Maybe even before you include the URL to your library(for testing).

Comment: Sounds good. Thank you very much! Been stuck on this issue for quite some time.